# Cant create s3 session

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, package, boto3

i am trying to download some data from our s3 server and im not being able to create the session.

i am running the following code:

```
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id = "###########",
    aws_secret_access_key = "###########",
)

s3 = session.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('########')
file_names = []
```

but it spits out the following error:

```
DataNotFoundError: Unable to load data for: sdk-default-configuration
```

These are my imports:

```
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector
import boto3
import s3fs
import botocore
import pandas as pd
import os
```

and my versions of boto3 and botocore installed are boto3-1.20.44 and botocore-1.23.44

I have tried downloading different versions of boto3 and botocore with no success...

Comment: Did you try `boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key)`?

Comment: Which line is generating the errors? It is the `session.resource('s3')` line? In general, you should never put your credentials in the code. Instead, use the AWS CLI `aws configure` command to store your credentials in a configuration file. Then, simply use `s3 = boto3.resource('s3')` and boto3 will automatically look for the credentials in the configuration file.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jarmod, that solved my problem

Comment: Thank you for your comment @John Rotenstein aswell, ill do that next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be in your session constructor:

```
boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=a, aws_secret_access_key=b)
```

It should instead read as follows, per the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html):

```
boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id=a, aws_secret_access_key=b)
```